# Sanitize jquery string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sanitization

In my case I use jQuery and PHP. I can add data width jQuery and when I do it creates new div tags.

The problem I have is if I add "My åäö test" to a div class for example it looks like this:

```
<div class="My åäö test">
```

In fact, that's three classes. I somehow need to sanitize it like the way Wordpress does:

[Sanitize Title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title)

My result should be:

```
<div class="my-aao-test">
```

Any other suggestions how to better store data attached to divs or other elements are also welcome.

Comment: Three classes, you mean, not two elements?

Comment: Why do you use classes for that instead of html5 `data` attributes?

Comment: @Delan Thanks for the input. Edited the post.

@TheifMaster I don't know. Thanks for the suggestion. Vote up for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use the same function that Wordpress uses?
You could pass it via ajax to be sanitized and then returned.
Taken from the source:

```
function sanitize_title_with_dashes($title) {
    $title = strip_tags($title);
    // Preserve escaped octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
    // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
    $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
    // Restore octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

    if (seems_utf8($title)) {
        if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
            $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
    }

    $title = strtolower($title);
    $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
    $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
    $title = trim($title, '-');

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A vote up for that one. I might go the ThiefMaster way and use HTML5 data attributes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Before you assign the class to the div use `.replace()` eg:

`$('myclass').replace(' ', '-');`

Comment: Of course, there are other illegal characters for classes such as `.` and so on. Maybe it's better to implement a *whitelist* of allowed characters.

Comment: @Jens Törnell; HAHA! well put, no worries mate.